# Listview gets popuplated from the database everytime I start the activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am fetching some json data into an EventApp and I am trying to store in SQLite database some of the events. I am showing the events in another activity, not the main one and whenever I go back from that activity to the main one and the I go back to the activity with the listview, the data gets duplicated every time. SO if I click to go to that activity 10 time, my data gets 10 times in the listview and in the database as well. How can I fix this?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add new row to the database
public void addEvent(Event ev){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, ev.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.START_DATE, ev.getStartTime());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.END_DATE, ev.getEndTime());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.IMAGE_URL, ev.getImageURL());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.URL, ev.getUrl());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.SUBTITLE, ev.getSubtitle());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION, ev.getDescription());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    //db.close();
}

//Delete event from database
public void deleteEvent(String eventTitle){
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE " + TITLE + "=\"" + eventTitle + "\";" );
}

public int deleteEvents() {
    return db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

//Print the database as string
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString="";

    //points to a location in results
    Cursor c = getEvents();

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
    }
    //db.close();
    return dbString;
}

public Cursor getEvents(){
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, ALL_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

This is the activity where I show the data from the database

```
public class StoredEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.stored_events);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_stored_events);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    events = (ArrayList<Event>) intent.getSerializableExtra("storedEvents");

    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_row, R.id.stored, events );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Here is the method that returns the stored events

```
public static ArrayList<Event> returnStoredEvents(){
    long id = -1;
    //getStoredEvents();
    Cursor c = eventsDB.getEvents();

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(eventsDB.ID));
        String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(eventsDB.TITLE));
        String start = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(eventsDB.START_DATE));
        String end = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(eventsDB.END_DATE));
        organizeEvents.add(new Event(title, start, end, true));
    }
    c.close();
    Log.d("DATABASE", organizeEvents.toString());
    return organizeEvents;
}
```

Here is where I actually add some of the events:

```
private void readEvents(String str){
    Event ev = null;
    try {
        JSONObject geoJSON = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray jsonEvents = geoJSON.getJSONArray("events");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonEvents.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject event = jsonEvents.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray timeJsonEvent = event.getJSONArray("datelist");
            JSONObject time = timeJsonEvent.getJSONObject(0);

            title = event.getString("title_english");

            Date date = new Date(time.getLong("start"));
            startDate = dateFormat.format(date);

            date = new Date(time.getLong("end"));
            endDate = dateFormat.format(date);

            imageURL = event.getString("picture_name");
            url = event.getString("url");
            subtitle = event.getString("subtitle_english");
            description = event.getString("description_english");

            if (title.charAt(0) == 'T') {
                ev = new Event(title, startDate, endDate, true);
                eventsDB.addEvent(ev);
            }else {
                    ev = new Event(title, startDate, endDate, false);
            }

            // Process a newly found event
            final Event finalEv = ev;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    addNewEvent(finalEv);
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is my main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
DatabaseHelper eventsDB;
ListFragment listFragment;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    eventsDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    //storedEvents.addAll(EventsListFragment.returnStoredEvents());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle().equals("Sort by name")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "ITEM 2 CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        EventsListFragment.sort(-1);
    }else if (item.getTitle().equals("Sort by date")) {
        EventsListFragment.sort(1);
    }else if (item.getTitle().equals("Stored events")){
        showSavedEvents();
        Toast.makeText(this, "ITEM 3 CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return true;
}

public void showSavedEvents(){
    intent = new Intent(this, StoredEventsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("storedEvents", EventsListFragment.returnStoredEvents());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: not clear from your code where the switch to StoredActivity taking place. Maybe your addNewEvent method inserts new event without duplicate check.

Comment: @Aurora Brignola clear the arraylist before inserting the values.

Comment: @dumb_terminal  very last method of the posted code

Comment: then I guess definitely the case that when you are fetching events and inserting them to db, duplicates are inserted. you have to check if it already exists in db, then insert if it doesn't.

Comment: @Jagjit Singh THANK YOU!!!!